# Python: How to encode a solution for an optimization problem

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on an optimization problem and needed to encode the solution to the problem. Below is the piece of code I wrote for this task. Part one of the extracts the corresponding cities assigned to each salesman. In Part two of the code, I want to insert the starting and ending depots (cities) of each of the salesmen. I want this process to be dynamic as the starting/ending depots lists will change as the "num_salesmen" variable changes. The "population_list" will hold members of the population. I have given one example to aid in your assistance of this request.

Please let me know if you need further clarification of my logic in the inserting part.

```
####____BELOW CODE is being designed encode a solution for a GA_____#
populationSize = 1 (this will be varied)
num_salesmen = 2
population_list = [[4, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]

    ## - where [4, 2, 3] is a list of cities to be visited by salesmen, 
    ## - [0, 1, 0] the list of salesman, and 
    ## - [1, 0], [1, 0] are the lists of starting and ending depots of the 
          salesman one (0) and salesman two (1) respectively.

for pop in population_list:  
    ##----Part ONE: determine cities assigned to each salesman:
    Assigned_cites = [[] for x in range(num_salesmen)]
    for i in range(len(pop[1])):
        for man in range(num_salesmen):
            if pop[1][i] == man:
               Assigned_cites[man].append(pop[0][i])

##---- Part TWO: inserting the starting and ending depots: 
for s_man in range(num_salesmen):
    for s_e_d in range(2,num_salesmen+2):         
        Assigned_cites[s_man].insert(0,pop[s_e_d][0])
        Assigned_cites[s_man].append(pop[s_e_d][1])

    ###- expected result from Part TWO Should look like below, but I am not getting it:
       [[1, 4, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#your extraction logic need a bit of tweaking    
Assigned_cites = [[] for x in range(num_salesmen)]
    for i in range(len(population_list[1])):
        for man in range(num_salesmen):
            if population_list[1][i] == man:
               Assigned_cites[man].append(population_list[0][i])
    print Assigned_cites
    s_man = 0 # no need of an outer for loop for sales man
    for s_e_d in range(2,num_salesmen+2):         
        Assigned_cites[s_man].insert(0,population_list[s_e_d][0])
        Assigned_cites[s_man].append(population_list[s_e_d][1])
        s_man = s_man + 1
    print Assigned_cites
```